# SQL Stored procedure using SET statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table called `@TempGeog`

```
Declare @TempGeog table (type VARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @statement1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @statement1 = 'insert into #CountyTemp   select th.STRLOGRECNO,tt.county from [DC_2010_'+@geographyType+'] th 
            inner join'+ @TempGeog +' tt on th.NAMELSAD10 = tt.county ;'
EXEC (@statement1);
```

I am not able to use the table `@TempGeog` inside my statement1.

> Error:Must declare scalar variable "@TempGeog"

My sql query should be built dynamically based on geography type the user has selected.

Comment: If the table is called `@TempGeog`, shouldn't it just be `inner join @TempGeog tt`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `@TempGeog` is not available in my statement. Hence I am not abe to perform inner join

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass table name in that fashion which I would not recommend. `@TempGeog` need to be declared as `varchar` datatype not `table` type.

works:

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(20) = 'MyTable'
DECLARE @set VARCHAR(100) = 'Select * from ' + @table
PRINT @set
```

fails:

```
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (id int)
DECLARE @set2 VARCHAR(100) = 'Select * from ' + @table2
PRINT @set2
```

based on your edit you need to change code to this

```
SET @statement1 = '
Declare @TempGeog table (type VARCHAR(MAX))

insert into #CountyTemp   select th.STRLOGRECNO,tt.county from [DC_2010_' + @geographyType + '] th 
                inner join  @TempGeog tt on th.NAMELSAD10 = tt.county ;'
EXEC (@statement1);
```

Comment: Still throws error in the runtime.

Must declare the table variable `@TempGeog`

Comment: Sorry forgot that if you want to use it like that you must declare it inside dynamic sql. I updated answer

Comment: If we declare like that it will replace the contents from the original table right?

Comment: Table variable are local anyway I'm still unclear what you were trying to do here.

Comment: In the `@TempGeog` table I have values `Illinois` `Texas` which are state names. I am passing an XML to stored procedure and storing these values into table. Since user has selected `STATE` the `@geographytype` is updated as `state` and finally I have to perform a join with @geographytype and @TempGeog

Comment: What database are you using?